# Error in my argument that $A^m=0$ implies $A^{m-1}=0$ for matrix $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, nilpotence

So nilpotent is the matrix where $A^m =0$ but $A^{m-1}$ is not equal to $0$. Well here's my logic-

$$A^{m-1} = I \cdot A^{m-1} = A^{-1} \cdot A \cdot A^{m-1} = A^{-1} \cdot A^m = A^{-1} \cdot 0 = 0$$

This gives $A^{m-1}$ always zero when $A^m=0$! Now I am sure there's some glitch in my logic so can someone point that out?
(Note that $A^{-1}$ here is inverse of matrix $A$)

Sorry for the weird symbols but I am not good at coding those math symbols.

Comment: welcome to MSE ^_^ I've edited your question to use MathJax so that it's easier to search in the future.

Comment: For this to happen $A^{-1}$ has to exist and this is the condition.

Comment: What do you mean by "So nilpotent is the matrix where $A^m=0$ but $A^{m−1}$ is not equal to $0$" ?

Comment: $A^{-1}$ does not exist, otherwise we will arrive at the contradiction that $I=A^m(A^{-1})^m=0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but you don't know if $A^{-1}$ actually exist. In fact it does not.

Say $$A =\pmatrix{0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0}\implies A^2 = \pmatrix{0&0&1\\0&0&0\\0&0&0}$$

and $A^3=0$. Notice that $A^{-1}$ does not exist since $\det A =0$.

---

Why it newer exists? If $\lambda$ is it eigenvalue and $v$ eigenvector, then we have $$Av = \lambda v\implies 0=A^{n}v =\lambda^n v \implies \lambda =0$$

So all it eigenvalues are $0$ and thus $\det A =0$ and so $A^{-1}$ does not exists.

Comment: Okayy so it does squish space to lower dimension and so determinant is zero. And if it squishes the inverse won't exist anyways. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You're assuming that $A^{-1}$ exists!

You'll find that nilpotent matrices cannot have inverses. In fact, your contradiction proves this!

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thank you so much for editing:) Can you elaborate on why it won't exist intuitively? Like I know that matrix multiplication represents transformation in space, let's say 2D for now. By math we can see that it won't exist but can't every transformation other than lowering space to 1D or 0D have a matrix that inverts its own effect?

Answer (score 2):

Since $A^{m-1} \ne 0$, there is $x \ne 0$ such that $y:=A^{m-1}x \ne 0.$ Then we get

$$Ay=A^mx=0.$$

This shows that $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. Therefore $A$ is not invertible.

Comment: Yes got it. Thanks.